# Grepping on du -h for all the files that are larger than 1GB

Tags: grep, regular-expression, disk-usage

So my disk is full, I am trying to grep for all the files larger than 1G. I tried searching for the word Sort in the man page of DU, but found nothing.

```
du -h . | grep -E "^\d*\.\d*G"
```

and also this.

```
du -h . | grep -E "^\d*?\.\d*?G"
```

I tried both of these command, but it is missing all the 1Gb files. My Regex-Fu is a bit rusty these days, so I figured I might just ask in stack-exchange.

Comment: you can just do with `du -h -t 1G`

Comment: and what if you had a Terabyte-sized file? I think you'd have an easier time if you didn't tell `du` to make the sizes human-readable, since you're now asking the computer to read the sizes.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have exactly 44GB on that drive :)

Comment: I see your point though.

Comment: Another handy tool for interactive disk space digging is `ncdu`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use find:

```
find . -type f -size +1G
```

Comment: Right .. but what was wrong with my regex?

Comment: Extended Regex doesn't know about `\d`, use PCRE (`grep -P`) or use `[0-9]`. Note that if `\.` doesn't work for some languages.

Comment: @aditya your regex was incorrect. As to why...? Ask a regex expert. You wanted help on solving a problem (finding files > 1G). https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Comment: Easy there now, I cannot accept answers with in 10 minutes of posting a question. I never said that I have an issue with his answer. I was just curious to know why my solution didn't work.